# I want to email the screenshot in tabular format stored in my local using C#?

Tags: c#, html, selenium, automation

I want to automate my work by sending the screenshot taken during automation in tabular email format [image: Like this] . I had successfully attached as document, but I want it in tabular format. This is code what I had already tried

```
public static void email_send() {

            string htmlBody = "<html><body><h1>Picture</h1><br><img src=\"cid:test1.jpeg\"></body></html>";
            AlternateView avHtml = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

            LinkedResource inline = new LinkedResource("test1.jpeg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
            inline.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            avHtml.LinkedResources.Add(inline);


            Attachment att = new Attachment(@"D:/test123.png");
            att.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;


            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.AlternateViews.Add(avHtml);
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("*****");
            mail.To.Add("*******");
            mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";


            mail.Body = String.Format(
             "<h3>Client: " +  " Has Sent You A Screenshot</h3>" +
             @"<img src=""cid:{0}"" />", inline.ContentId);

            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("******", "******");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the attachment.

Your linked resource also needs to be attached to the email. You need to add the following code:

```
mail.Attachments.Add(att);
```